# Exporting a data extension messes up the date format

Tags: dataextensions, date, datetime, data-export, format

I'm trying to export a Data Extension via a browser download. It is not a large data extension - around 2,000 records.
When I open up the exported file (a csv file), I get a mixture of two date formats:

[image]

There seems to be no logic to which date format it picks - m/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM or mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Format Cells]
Hope it can help. I think you can use the 'Format Cells' functionality and choose the 'Date' in Excel. Then you can get the format you wanna.

Comment: Thanks but when I do that, it converts those in the short format, but does not convert the ones in the longer format - I think it is reading those as text format rather than a date.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a datetime field in your CSV. You need to set the format of the column and then do the load.

[image]